# ASP.NET Core and CreateErrorResponse

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I want to return invalid ModelState from my API method and try to use as it was in Web Api:

```
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Test");
```

but it says, that

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1929  'HttpRequest' does not contain a definition for
>   'CreateErrorResponse' and the best extension method overload
>   'HttpRequestMessageExtensions.CreateErrorResponse(HttpRequestMessage,
>   HttpStatusCode, string)' requires a receiver of type
>   'HttpRequestMessage'

So, something changed in ASP.NET Core and I should include HttpRequestMessage as first parameter. But how to create it and why it's necessary in response at all?

**EDIT:**

I found, that invalid model can be returned by the following code:

```
return HttpBadRequest(ModelState);
```

but in any case, want to know flexible method to return my own error responses.

Comment: you can add and remove errors from ModelState

Comment: @tmg I can, but my problem that I want to return it to client so flexible, how I could in Web API 2

Comment: In dotnet core 2.0 you can use `return BadRequest(ModelState);`.

Comment: @AndreasHassing It seems `return HttpBadRequest(ModelState);` returns a different object model though, right? I ended up writing an extension method that took a `ModelStateDictionary` and returned `(string Message, Dictionary<string, string[]> ModelState)` (the latter holding all the error messages for each key) to approximate what had been sent before. Did `HttpBadRequest(ModelState);` work with your client without more changes?

Answer (score 2):

I found mono had not implemented these either; `System.Web.Http/HttpRequestMessageExtensions` adds extension methods to `System.Net.Http`.  You could do it yourself

```
namespace System.Web.Http
{
    public static class ApiControllerExtensions
    {
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot(ElementName = "Error", Namespace = "")]
        public class ErrorResponse
        {
            public string StatusCode { get; set; }
            public string Message { get; set; }
        }
        public static HttpResponseException CreateErrorResponseException(this ApiController controller, HttpStatusCode statusCode, string message)
        {
            ErrorResponse error = new ErrorResponse() 
            { 
                StatusCode = (int)statusCode + ": " + statusCode.ToString(),
                Message = message 
            };
            HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = controller.Request.CreateResponse(statusCode, error, controller.Request.GetConfiguration());
            return new HttpResponseException(responseMessage);
        }
    }
}
```